# Is kirpan allowed in Singapore MRT?

Tags: legal, singapore, religion, prohibited-items

After going through [this](http://sikhadvisoryboard.org/index.php/security-guidelines-on-the-kirpan/), I have found that,

> Kirpan is allowed to be carried in public if it meets the following security criteria:
>
> 1) The blade should not be more than 6 inches
>
> 2) The blade should be blunted or dull
>
> 3) It is to be sheathed at all times, and not openly displayed

Is kirpan allowed in Singapore MRT, if all the above rules are followed?

Is it necessary to explicitly declare it while security checking?

Comment: What is an MRT?

Comment: @DCTLib https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Rapid_Transit_(Singapore)

Comment: @DCTLib MRT is a Mass Transit system posing as rail based but in actuality based on some version or warp mode transportation. It allows fast translocation throughtout most of singapore at reasonable cost and overall has astounding utility. When arriiving at a station during rush hour the time for train stops - doors-open-people cascade out and in - doors close - train rolling is somewhere in the 15 +-/- a little range. Awesomely impressive. | Note that the machines which give coin change are not designed by cretins - you just need to realise the proper place to position your hand, or , whoops.

Answer (score 2):

The link you gave is from "**Sikh Advisory Board, Singapore**". They say "`Kirpan is allowed to be carried in public if it meets certain security criteria`". So MRT is a public transportation system and according to them (SAB, Singapore) you can carry Kirpan with you  in public i.e. also when you are using MRT. Only at checkpoints i.e. at Airports or Border crossing etc. you have to facilitate the screening processes in which you declare your Kirpan.

Comment: What are these "certain security criteria" and how would one verify they meet them?

Comment: @  Roddy of the Frozen Peas - Just read the OP. He has already described them in OP. You have very long name  lol :)

Comment: You can just say @Roddy ;-)